# How to create a frontend service using gcloud command for google balancer?

Tags: bash, command-line, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I could create some VM instances, add them to an instance group; also created an HTTP health check, and a backend service using `gcloud` command in a GCE project using these guides:

- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/http-health-checks/create
- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/backend-services/create

However, I can't find the doc to create a **frontend service** which is required to create a balancer, and indeed, the doc for creating balancer is also not available on [Google Cloud SDK Reference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/).

Is it real no way to use `gcloud` command to create frontend service and balancer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, it's called `forwarding-rules`, not frontend-services, rather confusing.

And forwarding rule won't point directly to a backend-service. Forwarding rule (global) points to **Target HTTP Proxy**, and Target HTTP Proxy needs a **URL Map**.

Reference:

- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/forwarding-rules/create

Credit to the answer of @eSniff here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28533614/5581893